# @PrePersist is triggered, @PostLoad is not

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

i'm trying to use JPA EntityListeners to log database operation in a Spring Boot Application.

Entity:

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(DatabaseLogger.class)
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ApiUser implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5645062676198141323L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @NonNull
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;

    @NonNull
    private String password;

}
```

DatabaseLogger.class:

```
public class DatabaseLogger {

    @PrePersist
    public static void userPrePersist(final ApiUser user) {
        System.out.println("PrePersist triggered");
    }

    @PostLoad
    public static void userPostLoad(final ApiUser ob) {
        System.out.println("PostLoad triggered");
    }

}
```

When i call the save method of the corresponding repository, the method DatabaseLogger#userPrePersist is triggered. But when i call the findAll method of the repository, the method DatabaseLogger#userPostLoad is not. Does anyone have an idea, why the @PrePerist method is called while the @PostLoad method isn't?

Answer (score 0):

Add `spring.jpa.show-sql: true` to be sure that you make a select call to the database.

In fact, if findAll() returns an empty collection then @PostLoad is not going to be triggered. Make sure that you obtain data from the database as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Already set show-sql to true. select call to database is executed and there is definitely data retrieved. But @PostLoad is not called.